# Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified

Tags: java

I am getting this error when I typed `gradlew run -Pargs="message"` in the terminal window of android studio to send a message to the app.

Error occurred during initialization of VM:

> Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified.

Default value in Environment variables set for java is:

`-Xmx512m -Xms1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your starting heap size `-Xms` is greater than your max head size `-Xmx`. You could fix this error by setting Initial heap size `<=` Max heap size.

Comment: I have changed the value to this:    -Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m         Still im getting the same error

Comment: yeah again because your permSize is 256m greater than Xms, you could use something like this: -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m

Comment: Thanks but still  I am getting the same error, I have changed it in Environment variables Java_opts is there any other file where i have to change this?

Comment: you need to change it wherever this is wrong, can you paste the output of running gradle from command line

Comment: <a href="http://imgur.com/pOd1Crp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pOd1Crp.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: got it, ```-Xmx1024m``` is incorrect, you are missing a ```:```, use this string, ```-Xmx:1024m -Xms:512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m```

Comment: No still getting the same